# Using “com.worklight.common.WLPreferences” to export the component raising security concern

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

A malicious application on the same device can cause a crash by submitting malformed data to the exported components. To overcome such vulnerability, how can one implement data validation mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

The “com.worklight.common.WLPreferences” activity is added to a MobileFirst hybrid application for adding a preferences screen to  application where certain connection parameters can be edited during the execution of the app. This is a feature that is meant for use in the development environment and not recommended for use in production environment. On a production environment, one can remove this activity from the AndroidManifest.xml file to resolve this vulnerability.